# Restarting init without restarting the system

Tags: init

In [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/871331/ghost-glibc-vulnerability-cve-2015-0235-is-it-required-restart-a-server-after), the accepted answers states that

> For example, /sbin/init uses glibc [the vulnerable lib], and restarting that without a reboot is non-trivial.

Now, non-trivial is [engineer'ish for impossible](http://web.archive.org/web/20071103092812/http://xooglers.blogspot.com/2005/11/word.html), but I'm still curious:

Is it possible to restart init without restarting the whole system?

Comment: In this case, “non-trivial” is engineerish for “I don't know how to do it”.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
telinit u
```

will restart `init` without affecting the rest of the system.

Comment: Not a that crazy work arround as I expected/hoped for, but correct. Thank you :)

Comment: I can't imagine that the sysv init does any calls to gethostbyname() etc., and certainly not with data that comes from outside of the system so I don't consider restarting `init` a priority in the context of the ghost bug.

Comment: This works for sysvinit and systemd (equivalent to `systemd daemon-reexec`).

Comment: This doesn't work with all init implementations on all Unix variants (IIRC on AIX you're out of work), but as far as I know it does work with all init implementations that might be linked with glibc.

Answer (score 3):

A simple `init u` does the trick!

Afterwards, `zypper ps` doesn't report deleted files of the init process any more.